# svn copy : copy the entire directory to the another directory

Tags: svn, svn-copy

I need to copy the entire directory to another URL.

```
   svn copy http://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/trunk/Test http://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/trunk/Test7
```

It's working properly (i.e. entire `/Test` directory copied to `/Test7` successfully at first time).

If I modify some of the files in `/Test` directory and again copy `/Test` to `/Test7` directory, it will copy the `/Test` directory under the `/Test7` directory like `/Test7/Test`. If i again try to copy the `/Test` Directory to `/Test7` directory, it shows an error:

> svn: E160020: Path 'Test' already exists

But I want to commit the modified files only to the `/Test7` directory when I copy at second time. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to delete 'Test7' and only then copy (this will require 2 revisions creation). Alternatively you could do that via working copy (delete Test7, copy Test). Or, if there're no changes in Test7, you can merge Test into Test7 (will require working copy too).

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the old directory first, then copy again.

And - read the documentation, it's really very helpful. `svn help`is good as well.

Answer (score -1):

> How can i do this ?

### [Read docs!!!](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html)

If you modify files in WC, related to Test and want to mirror changes into Test7 - you have to use

- correct workflow
- correct commands

You can:

- switch WC to Test7 path and commit
- switch WC to Test7, update, merge Test into WC, commit

Comment: Here is the my understanding:                                     switch WC to Test7(switch the working copy of Test to url of Test7) & Commit, Switch WC(working copy of Test7 to url of Test, update Test7 ,Merge Test7 into working copy of Test & commit............... Is this is correct ?